# One of three functions not being called using QAndroidJniObject

Tags: java, android, c++, qt

Here is the code that calls three functions from my custom java class:

```
QAndroidJniObject datafile = QAndroidJniObject::fromString(path);
QAndroidJniObject password = QAndroidJniObject::fromString("asimpletest");

QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("org/qcolocrypt/AESCrypt",
                                          "AESCryptInit",
                                          "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V;",
                                          password.object<jstring>(),
                                          datafile.object<jstring>());


QAndroidJniObject decrypted_data = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("org/qcolocrypt/AESCrypt",
                                                                             "decrypt",
                                                                             "()Ljava/lang/String;");


QAndroidJniObject fname = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("org/qcolocrypt/AESCrypt",
                                                                   "getFilename",
                                                                   "()Ljava/lang/String;");

QAndroidJniObject status = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("org/qcolocrypt/AESCrypt",
                                                                   "getStatus",
                                                                   "()Ljava/lang/String;");
```

Here is the java code for three of these functions:

The non working one:

```
public static void AESCryptInit (String passwd, String datafile){

    // Initializing variables.
    rawdata = null;
    status = "";
    fileName = datafile;

    Log.i("[QCOLOCRYPT]","The filename is " + datafile);

    // Transforming the passwd to 16 bytes.
    try {
        MessageDigest digester = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(Charset.forName(encoding).encode(passwd).array());
        byte[] buffer = new byte[NCHARS];
        int byteCount;
        while ((byteCount = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            digester.update(buffer, 0, byteCount);
        }
        keyBytes = digester.digest();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        status = "Error in key generation: " + e.toString();
    }

    // Initilizing the crypto engine
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        status = "Error in intialization: " + e.toString();
    }
    secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
    ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(keyBytes);

}
```

And two that work

```
// Getting status
public static String getStatus(){return status;}

public static String getFilename() {
   Log.i("[QCOLOCRYPT]","Getting the file name");
   return "The Filename is: " + fileName;
}
```

The non-working function is not being called because its debug message is NOT being printed, while I get the log message AND the return values of the other two. Logcat does not seem to show any errors, so I'm at a loss. Am I calling it wrong?

Comment: If you are using Qt then read the logs very carefully. If any issue is there it will be traced. I had very hard times in understanding Qt logs myself.

Comment: Which logs. I do adb logcat, do you mean those logs?

Comment: Because there is litterally NO output of any kind between a message I've added (using qDebug) just before the function is called the the Log message in the getFilename() function.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this isn't exactly an answer. It's more of a workaround, I got the function to work, but the only way I could do it is by returning a String. I've tried with an Integer using (Arguments)I; as the signature but I had the same problem. I modified the Java function to return a status string, changed the signature to reflect that, and everything worked perfectly. Though its weird.